# MySQL subquery returning more than one row, how to workaround?

Tags: mysql

whilst I'm not entirely new to MySQL and I've got the basics, I'm struggling with the following code, subquery of which is returning more than one row - which is supposed to. My question to you all is how do you make it work with multiple rows, to put it in perspective, there are multiple results of the subquery and I got to get the results from each.

```
select distinct * from oglasi where id = (select distinct zanimanja_oglasi.id_o from zanimanja_oglasi, zanimanja_uporabniki where zanimanja_oglasi.id_z = zanimanja_uporabniki.id_z and zanimanja_uporabniki.id_u = 3) order by id desc limit 50
```

(For the following I get the mentioned error, #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row and I do understand that error is supposed to be there, my question is how to format the code so that it can accept more than one subquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use IN instead of =

```
 select distinct * from oglasi where id IN (select distinct ...
                                        ^^
```

Comment: You're welcome, accepting (click the green check mark) the answer that help you the most is the best way to say thanks here on SO :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `in` keyword like so:

```
select distinct * 
from oglasi 
where id IN (
  select distinct zanimanja_oglasi.id_o 
  from zanimanja_oglasi 
  inner join zanimanja_uporabniki 
    on zanimanja_oglasi.id_z = zanimanja_uporabniki.id_z 
    and zanimanja_uporabniki.id_u = 3
) 
order by id desc limit 50
```

You can also try out the `where exists` keywords like so:

```
select distinct * 
from oglasi o
where exists (
  select 1
  from zanimanja_oglasi 
  inner join zanimanja_uporabniki 
    on zanimanja_oglasi.id_z = zanimanja_uporabniki.id_z 
    and zanimanja_uporabniki.id_u = 3
  where zanimanja_oglasi.id_o = o.id
) 
order by id desc limit 50
```

Giorgos mentioned about using `inner join`, which is pretty neat also.

Answer (score 0):

Use `INNER JOIN` instead:

```
select distinct * 
from oglasi as t1
inner join (
   select distinct zanimanja_oglasi.id_o as id
   from zanimanja_oglasi, zanimanja_uporabniki 
   where zanimanja_oglasi.id_z = zanimanja_uporabniki.id_z and 
         zanimanja_uporabniki.id_u = 3 
) AS t2 on t1.id = t2.id
order by t1.id desc limit 50
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'll look into inner joins, apparently in instead of equals solved this very problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check this.

```
 select distinct oglasi.* from oglasi
 inner join zanimanja_oglasi on (zanimanja_oglasi.id_o=oglasi.id)
 inner join on (zanimanja_oglasi.id_z = zanimanja_uporabniki.id_z)
 where zanimanja_uporabniki.id_u = 3
order by oglasi.id desc limit 50;
```

Answer (score 0):

A subquery is allowed to return more than 1 row when you use "IN" or "ANY"

I think your query should be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
    FROM oglasi
    WHERE id IN (SELECT DISTINCT zanimanja_oglasi.id_o
        FROM zanimanja_oglasi, zanimanja_uporabniki
        WHERE zanimanja_oglasi.id_z = zanimanja_uporabniki.id_z
        AND zanimanja_uporabniki.id_u = 3)
        ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50
```

Or

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
    FROM oglasi
    WHERE id = ANY (SELECT DISTINCT zanimanja_oglasi.id_o
        FROM zanimanja_oglasi, zanimanja_uporabniki
        WHERE zanimanja_oglasi.id_z = zanimanja_uporabniki.id_z
        AND zanimanja_uporabniki.id_u = 3)
        ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50
```

IMHO it's better to use the IN though.

Hope this helps.